# Cannot access python object attribute even though I can see it exist

Tags: python

AttributeError: 'File' object has no attribute 'Csapat'
[image]

```
class File:
    columns = list(firstLine("focivb.txt"))

    def __init__(self, *args):
        index = 0
        for arg in args:
            try:
                arg = int(arg)
            except:
                arg = str(arg)
            if isinstance(arg, int):
                setattr(self, self.columns[index][0], arg)

                self.columns[index][1] = "int"
                index += 1
            if isinstance(arg, str):
                setattr(self, self.columns[index][0], arg)
                self.columns[index][1] = "string"
                index += 1
```

```
def readFile(file):
    with open(file, "r", encoding="utf-8") as read:

        content = read.readlines()

        isFirstLine = True
        for line in content:
            obj = line.split("\t")
            if isFirstLine:
                isFirstLine = False
                continue
            for i in range(len(obj)):
                yield File(*obj)
```

```
objs = list(readFile("focivb.txt"))
for i in objs:
    print(getattr(i, "Csapat"))



def firstLine(file):
    with open(file, "r", encoding="utf-8") as read:
        content = read.readlines()
        for i in range(len(content[0].split('\t'))):
            yield [content[0].split('\t')[i], 0]
```

I was trying to read any file to later convert it to an sql table

fillertextfillertextfillertextfillertextfillertextfillertextfillertextfillertext

Comment: try `getattr(i, "Csapat")`

Comment: `for i in range(len(content[0].split('\t'))):
            yield [content[0].split('\t')[i], 0]` is horrible. just iterate on the split result and yield the elements...

Comment: try getattr(i, "Csapat"). Still doesn't work. I tried that originally but forgot to edit it back

Comment: then [edit] your question to show your latest attempt